# Is there a way to extract a specific html tag info with NCrawler

Tags: c#, .net, web-crawler

Specs: Win7 64, VS 2010, .NET 4.0, NCrawler library 
I'm writing a crawler that will extract some data from a online shop. The application extracts the URLs fine, and I can navigate to every item from the shop properly. The problem is that every "propretyBag" object that keeps all the page data of the product is in a text form, I was wondering if there is a way to read the contents of a specific tag like <-description>Text<-/descriptopn> from this "propertyBag" or there is another way to do it.
THx

Answer (score 0):

You need a HTML parser like HtmlAgilityPack (http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to extract the required information.

But I would recommend to use Abot (https://code.google.com/p/abot/) as web crawler. It is an activly developed free open source web crawler written in C#.
Abot has built in HTML parsers like HtmlAgilityPack (extract elements via XPath) and CsQuery (extract elements via CSS selectors).

Comment: Thx, I'll try the agility pack and get back with the response.

Comment: If I add the AgilityPack as a Reference to NCrawler.Demo project, the demo app from the NCrawler extracts just 1 single URL(the main page: http://ncrawler.codeplex.com/ ). Without the AgilityPack reference the NCrawler demo extracts all the URLs. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: solve it, thx, it worked in combination NCrawler+HTMLAgilityPack